# Android Dynamic tabs(fragments) with dynamic listviews

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-fragments, tabs

i am developing a android app where i have a fragment which will have dynamic tabs(tabs will be depend on server data) and in this dynamic tabs a same listview is reused for every fragment

1) now the problem is how can i fetch data from edittext present in listview between - and +  reused in every fragment

2)  how can i retain data in every in every listview when i move between activity's

to have an idea i am posting a image of my app which i roughly done

https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3ewK.png

how to save data SQLite db or shared preferences

please answer soon

```
    public class ServicesListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Products> {
    ArrayList<Products> actorList;
    LayoutInflater vi;
    int Resource;

    public ServicesListAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Products> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        vi = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        Resource = resource;
        actorList = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 500;
    }



    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // convert view = design
        View v = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;


        if (v == null) {
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.booking_show, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.service = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            holder.price = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text2);
            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }       


               // String[] wash1 = actorList.get(position).getName().split(",", -1);



        Toast.makeText(getContext(),""+actorList.get(position).getName(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        holder.service.setText(actorList.get(position).getName());

        holder.price.setText(actorList.get(position).getPrice());


        return v;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {

        public TextView service;
        public TextView price;

    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

**1)** You need to add text change listener to your edittext: yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()) in which you will save text.

**2)** You need to create DataBase or use SharedPreferences to do that. Also if you are using activities but not the fragments, you can pass data using intents.

**Simple example of creating SharedPreferences:**

```
SharedPreferences yourpreferences = getSharedPreferences("Specify_tag", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor youreditor = yourpreferences.edit();
youreditor.putString("name", "Put_data_here");
youreditor.commit();
```

You can put not only strings but almost types of data;

To access your shared preferences in other activity use:

```
SharedPreferences yourpreferences = getSharedPreferences("Specified_tag", MODE_PRIVATE);
your_variable = yourpreferences.getString("name_you_specify","def_value");
```

where "def_value" is default value(change it if you want)

I hope my answer was helpful for you

Comment: hi Alex RED i am using fragments in listview how can i retain data when i move to another fragments as you can see pic that i given as a link when ever i move to another fragment list is getting refreshed and edittext data is lost

Comment: You need to create a custom adapter with ViewHolder. This will help you while switching between fragments but your data will be lost once you close your app. I think you need a database to save your data.

Comment: ya i have created View Holder previously attached the file for you in my question please look at it and please try to add functionality to save listview data